# How to give power to raspberry with combination 1.5v battries?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am new with raspberry ,was looking for a ways to give power to raspberry with combination of 1.5v batteries. Is there any way to do so ? Any hint or link will be useful.

Comment: There is a stackexchange site dedicated to the Raspberry Pi. You may want to ask there.  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: great! never knew of this site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that connecting 3 of them in series shoul be enought, better if four 1.2V - 1.25V, or maybe you should check something like [this](http://www.electroschematics.com/tag/dc-dc-converter-circuits/).
You may also consider using a usb power bank.

Comment: Pardon me for un clear question, my question was more about how i should design that micro usb power interface for raspberry or we have some connector for that ? do let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: If you want you can build one from scratch. If you take a micro USB cable and open it you should find a red and a black tiny cables, if you connect them directly with the series of batteries it should work. You should also find some battery slot for making everything easyer, but i would probably do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Might take a look at a boost circuit, something like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1903?gclid=Cj0KEQiAn8i0BRDur-HV1PCTy4UBEiQAPuFr9Km6oqfR32Z0Q1SYP4kP8t0ISJbiH07RGks-uhQ0lcMaAi6Q8P8HAQ), that allows for an input voltage as low as 1.8vdc and boosts the output to 5vdc.